# redirigir al checkout de stripe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, stripe

Tengo mi sitio web en ruby on rails 5 y estoy actualizando mi metodo de pago de stripe con este [enlace](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/set-up-a-subscription#create-checkout-session), pero al presionar el boton no redirige a checkout de stripe, esto es lo que tengo en el controlador:

```
def index

    Stripe.api_key = Rails.configuration.stripe[:secret_key]

    session = Stripe::Checkout::Session.create(
      payment_method_types: ['card'],
      line_items: [{
        price: 'price_1HKywnBS16ZK5Vr3GYCRvTir',
        quantity: 1,
      }],
      mode: 'subscription',
      success_url: 'https://www.my_site.network/success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
      cancel_url: 'https://www.my_site.network/cancel',
    )

end
```

creo que el error puede estár acá en mi vista cuando intento insertar el id de la sesión:

```
<button id="checkout-button">Pay</button>

<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var stripe = Stripe('<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>');

    var checkoutButton = document.getElementById('checkout-button');


    checkoutButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
      stripe.redirectToCheckout({
        // Make the id field from the Checkout Session creation API response
        // available to this file, so you can provide it as argument here
        // instead of the {{CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}} placeholder.
        sessionId: '<%=session.id%>'
      }).then(function (result) {
        // If `redirectToCheckout` fails due to a browser or network
        // error, display the localized error message to your customer
        // using `result.error.message`.
      });
    });




</script>
```

en la consola del navegador me muestra el siguiente error al clickear el boton:

```
(index):1 Uncaught IntegrationError: stripe.redirectToCheckout: Invalid value for sessionId. You specified '340b63dc228dcafdd225f23ee789b573'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sin realmente saber cómo funciona esto, lo que me salta a la vista es que no estás definiendo `session` como una variable de instancia `@session`. Si no haces esto, no puedes acceder a ella desde la plantilla:

```rb
def index
  Stripe.api_key = Rails.configuration.stripe[:secret_key]
  @session = Stripe::Checkout::Session.create(...)
end
```

Una vez hagas esto, en la plantilla podrás acceder a `@session`:

```
sessionId: '<%= @session.id %>'
```

La razón por la que no protesta que `session` no existe, es porque Rails ya define algo llamado `session` (la sesión de usuario, guardada en las cookies). Si sólo haces `session.id`, le estás dando a Stripe la id de sesión equivocada.

Comment: muchas gracias, tienes razón, estaba accediendo a la session del usuario, ya una vez la guardé en @session ya estuvo disponible en la vista, estuve intentando solucionarlo por horas, muchas gracias.